# Chatgpt api responses are different in diffrerent api keys

Tags: openapi, langchain, chatgpt-api

I have developed a langchain summarization using chatgpt api 3.5 turbo, when i use different type of keys for the summarization the structure of the summary is changing. how can i short out this problem?

summarization output without changing the structure

Answer (score 0):

You prompt role should not change between the API keys, usually the output of the model should be same. So, make sure you have well defined prompt and it does not change when you change the API keys..